# Uninstall programms installed by Ubuntu 20.04 LTS setup process

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I installed programs via the setup process of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (namely docker and prometheus).

These programs do not appear to be installed in any "normal fashion", meaning I neither do find them via `apt list --install` nor by using `dpkg`.

I now dont need prometheus anymore, and the docker installation is having version issues and cannot be updated via `apt-get update / upgrade`.

How do I find and remove these programs ?

Comment: Run `snap list`. Are docker and prometheus listed?

Comment: @user535733 yes docker and prometheus are listed with `snap list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by following the comment of user535733 in the comment of my question.

Running `snap list` and then `snap remove <name>` got rid of them.

Thanks user535733!